# Notebook for developer (Android Studio)

Tags: laptop, development

I want to buy notebook for programming. I am Android developer and work in Android Studio. So now I choose between to models Lenovo.

1. **Lenovo IdeaPad 520-15IKB (80YL00LXRA)**

   15.6" IPS (1920x1080) Full HD, / Intel Core i5-8250U (1.6 - 3.4 ГГц) / RAM 16 GB / HDD 1 TB + SSD 128 GB / nVidia GeForce MX150, 4 GB
2. **Lenovo IdeaPad 520-15IKB (81BF00EGRA)** - more expensive (about 80-100$)

   15.6" IPS (1920x1080) Full HD,/ Intel Core i7-8550U (1.8 - 4.0 ГГц) / RAM 16 GB/ HDD 1 TB + SSD 128 GB/ nVidia GeForce MX150, 4 GB

What do you think about that models? Does it make sense to take a laptop that is more expensive (81BF00EGRA) because of a better processor? Or propose please some others notebooks. I want that Android Studio will work very fast, because now it's very slow :)

Comment: What lead you to choose these two notebooks intially?

Answer (score 1):

There is obviously no definite answer. But in my opinion, if you can afford it you should certainly take the better one.

The difference between the processors is not a small one but a huge difference in performance (mainly in multi-core workloads) between this 7th gen dual-core i5 and the 8th gen quad-core i7.

In [**CPU Benchmarks**](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp[]=3064&cmp[]=2865) it just blows it away with a score of **8109** to the i5s **4665**. (I know benchmarks aren't showing the whole picture, but it shows you something.)

Also, the GPU is somewhat better in the more expensive one.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion between these two notebooks, though you should note that the 8550U is going to draw more power (the TDP-down is a 10W vs 7.5W, not even accounting for turbo or Lenovo's tweaks.) In any case I'm wondering if there's something else better. Neither of these are cheap, and IMO, at that price point, there are far more compelling offerings.

Answer (score 1):

You can take any of them between these two. Because both laptop has overkill specification according to the requirements of `Android Studio`. Android Studio requires SSD and 8GB Ram to perform well. But both of the laptop has 16GB.

=> **Lenovo IdeaPad 520-15IKB (80YL00LXRA)** would be ideal choice if you don't want to spend more. But if you're looking for more performance, then you should go for **Lenovo IdeaPad 520-15IKB (81BF00EGRA)**

=> **Lenovo IdeaPad 520-15IKB (81BF00EGRA)** will def build Android Studio projects faster than **Lenovo IdeaPad 520-15IKB (80YL00LXRA)**

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, the Android Studio Emulator works better with Intel CPUs. It has Intel Haxm and better compatibility.

You can certainly still run the emulators via AMD cpus but may need some additional configuration.

On another note, RAM is very important... I would go for 16 GB at a minimum to be able to run Android Studio at the same time as an Emulator, web browser, etc.